# Jupyter Notebook kernel dying in the middle of running code

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, random-walk

I am trying to run this code in jupyter notebook and it runs halfway but then the kernel restarts and the code stops running. Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ant(nx, ny, nmoves):
    arr = np.ones((ny, nx))

    ix = nx//2
    iy = ny//2
    dx, dy = 1, 0
    for i in range(nmoves):
        if arr[iy,ix]:
            dx, dy = dy, -dx
        else:
            dx, dy = -dy, dx
        arr[iy,ix] = 1 - arr[iy,ix]
        ix, iy = ix+dx, iy+dy   
        
        %matplotlib osx 
        
        fig = plt.imshow(arr, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)

nx = 175
ny = 175
nmoves = 13000
ant(nx, ny, nmoves)
```

I tried reducing the particles to 5000 but still the kernel would restart and stop running the code. It's important for the particles to be a high number so that a repeating pattern in the output could be seen.

Comment: You should look at the Jupyter logs to see why it's restarting. There really should be some sort of error when the kernel is killed - my guess is it's running out of memory.

Comment: @AKX how do you look at Jupyter logs? and if it is running out of memory, is there a fix?

Comment: I'd look at the console you started Jupyter from..? Hard to tell without further details about your system. As for the second question, write your code in a way that uses less memory. For instance, should you maybe try to clean up your drawings every now and then (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-clear-the-memory-completely-of-all-matplotlib-plots for instance)